# System.OutOfMemoryException when trying to use ToDictionary on a LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, exception, dictionary

I am trying to populate a dictionary object from a sales table that has 6 million records. This is because the original linq query times out. I am joining 3 or 4 tables to the sales table and it is just too much and times out. I thought I could get the sales table in memory to prevent the time out from sql server.

My code is:

```
var sales = dc.Sales
    .Where(c => c.Active == true)
    .Select(s => s)
    .ToDictionary(s => s.Id, s => s);
```

Does anyone know how to get my dictionary object to populate without raising an out of memory exception?

Comment: So you have so much data the query is timing out and you are trying to load everything into memory to fix that? Where is logic in that?

Comment: Why dont you try extracting a fixed no of records like (10000) in each query and maintain a sequence counter that increments everytime to help you fetch the next batch of records

Comment: I understand but most of the time we load data into dictionaries to speed up the application and just join the dictionaries together and extract the data. We do most of the stuff in memory. This normally works but this is the first time I have hit 6 million records so am trying to figure out a way to make this work. We normally do not use stored procedures on the team - we normally use linq to sql and do most work in memory. This may not be possible what I am trying to do but wanted to see if anyone has had a similar situation and can offer some advice. Thanks for any input!

Comment: Just buy more memory :-).  Joking aside, this will never work efficiently.  You need to do whatever it is you are trying to do in smaller batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the feedback. I found out what was causing the out of memory exception. I decided to not use a dictionary because it was just not going to work. I went to sql server and replicated my linq query and ran it and only got 30,000 records back. So I knew that the linq query was not causing the out of memory. My original query was just a simple lookup to the database with a few .Where() clauses. Turns out that I was doing a .Distinct() on the collection that was populated with the 30,000 records and this was causing the out of memory exception. I removed the .Distinct() call on the linq query and it fixed it. The out of memory exception makes sense because it was trying to handle 30,000 records in the collection and distinct them and it was just to much to compare.

Comment: I don't understand why Distinct on 30k records would fail. Do you have any documentation to support this hypothesis?

Answer (score 2):

This question hints at serious misunderstanding how database querying works. Usually, when query is timing out, you have to limit the data you are pulling out. If you really have to pull so much data (which I think is error in business requirements), then you should pull them in batches.

> we normally use linq to sql

Linq-to-SQL has been depreciated for years now. It is practically incompetent in creating usable SQL queries. This is probably why are you getting the timeouts. I would consider LINQ-to-SQL not only as bad choice, but outright risk equivalent to bomb in your software that is ready to explode. You should either move to Entity Framework with LINQ-to-Entities or use hand-crafted SQL. This hints at second problem:

> we load data into dictionaries to speed up the application and just join the dictionaries together and extract the data

I never heard anyone who would ever use this approach or consider it acceptable to use. SQL does this easily and much faster. If your team really thinks this is the way to do things, then serious study of SQL is required.

Answer (score -1):

I Would suggest using  ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; to enable the lazy loading and then when the data is required then required entities will be loaded on its own. The loaded entities can then remain in the context and reused if you do not close the context and open again.
I have tried the program with 100000 entities and using lazy loading allow the object required to be opened instantly.